# How to replace some character in mysql column by 'x'?

Tags: php, mysql

I have emails like this

```
uuak6G6GgD@gmail.com
d3lferM@gmail.com
Efqc9@gmail.com
```

How to convert and select like this.

```
uuakxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
d3lfxxx@xxxxx.xxx
Efqcx@xxxxx.xxx
```

Yes I am able to get this value but, I am not good enough in mysql function so please help me to make it simple and short if possible. And also suggest what other solution would be to make it.

I have created my query as

```
 SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(email,
 4),SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(email,'[a-z0-9]',"x"),5)),email
 FROM `users`
```

I am using `PHP` as server side, so If we could involve php to make good enough, please also suggest.

Your help and suggestions are heartily appreciable.

Comment: Is the `xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx` will be of fixed length irrespective of email length or x will be replaced for every character?

Comment: No its not fixed , Except first four character and `@` symbol I want to replace all character by `x`. Also I have updated sample output.

Comment: I would do this in php

Comment: I think there's no such function `(REGEXP_REPLACE)` in MySQL. If you want to do it in PHP it can be easily done

Comment: @Uchiha, I am using from here :  https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the point is obfuscation of email addresses, then you should not replace the characters by x, thus giving indication on the length of the email address. Just take the first 4 characters (left() function) and add a fixed ending of "xxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx". You also need to decide how to handle email addresses where the user part is shorter than 4 characters.

Comment: Yes I just wanted to indicate users to see only first 4 character, I am creating this business logic first time, so I don't know if it works or not if number of characters in email are different ?

Comment: Thanks it really helped, Also I am including `IF` to check shorter than 4 and replace all character by `x`. My thinking is to first try to fetch data as much as manipulated from DB and then server side and then in client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this using PHP you can simply use the following `regex` along with `preg_replace` function like as

```
(^(\w){1,4}|@|\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)
```

**Example :**

```
echo preg_replace("/(^(\w){1,4}|@|\.)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)/","$1x","uuak6G6GgD@gmail.com");
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer for what @gaurav is trying to do, but not, what he should be doing.

Comment: @DainisAbols, Yes definitely It should be the answer for PHP, But I am trying first to use by mysql query, Thanks for sharing your thought.

Comment: I just shared the another way irrespective of MySQL that's why I've specify to achieve this using PHP @gaurav while going through the following statement defined in question _I am using PHP as server side, so If we could involve php to make good enough, please also suggest._

Comment: @Uchiha , sorry If I was unclear anywhere, But I tried to say php in query like sometime we use `php implode` with mysql `IN` clause, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails = [
    'uuak6G6GgD@gmail.com',
    'd3lferMGo7@gmail.com',
    'Efqc90dUGI@gmail.com',
    'I@gmail.com',
];

$modded = [];
foreach ($emails as $item) {
    $name = explode('@', $item);
    $name = str_pad(substr($name[0], 0, 4), 4, "x");
    $modded[] = $name . 'xxxx@xxx.xxx';
}

var_dump($modded);
```

Comment: Number of character before and after converted should be same, I have update sample output in my question.

Comment: I do not suggest to to use the same length

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like :

`$email = substr($email, 0, 4) . preg_replace('/\w/', 'x', substr($email, 4));`

Doing it in the MySQL query is usually not reasonnable imo. MySQL isn't very good at that kind of data transformation.

Comment: What will happen when email is *a@gmail.com* ?

Answer (score 0):

involve php, select record and than
Break every email address in two parts

```
$email = 'I@gmail.com';
$email = explode('@', $email);
$firstPart = $email[0];
$lastPart =  $email[1];
$first4 = substr($firstPart, 0, 4);
$mid = preg_replace('/[^.@\-]/', 'x', substr($firstPart, 4));
$last = preg_replace('/[^.@\-]/', 'x', $lastPart);
$converted = $first4.$mid.'@'.$last;
```

Comment: What will happen when email is *a@gmail.com* ?

Comment: is this possible that email includes / ?

Comment: That's was a capital **i** :D

Comment: oops, but is this possible that email have only I@gmail.com
email format need 4 char before @gmail.com

Comment: The shortest valid email address may consist of only two parts: name and domain `name@domain` Since both the name and domain may have the length of 1 character, the minimal total length resolves to 3 characters. So the **entire** email can be only 3 characters.

Comment: Yor are right, i update my answer but it's look like your answer :D